# ruby on rails and Kaminari pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, kaminari

I'm using Kaminari to paginate many schools objects but I have to order them by ratings, but something went wrong : the pagination is ok but the gem order by rating for each page of the pagination, and not for all schools present in all page, for example :

```
page 1 -> school 1 - rate 20, school 2 - rate 10, school 3 - rate 0
page 2 -> school 4 - rate 12, school 5 - rate 6, school 7 - rate 0
page 3 -> ...
```

and I want :

```
page 1 -> school 1 - rate 200, school 2 - rate 120, school 3 - rate 100
page 2 -> school 4 - rate 90, school 5 - rate 90, school 6 - rate 85
...
```

here is my code :

```
def index
  @schools = School.where(:subscription.exists => false).page(params[:page]).per(50)
  @schoolss = @schools.sort_by(&:ratings_count).reverse
end
```

and the view

```
  <tbody>
    <% @sch.each do |school| %>
        <tr>
          <th> <%= link_to school.title, school.path_school_profile %> </th>
          <th> <%= school.city %> </th>
          <th> <%= school.ratings.count %> avis | <%= school.avg_ratings_score_round %>/5 </th>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= paginate @schools %>
<%= page_entries_info @schools %>
```

Does someone could help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you sorted @schools to new variable(@schoolss), why not use it??

change your index controller to this

```
def index
  @schools = School.where(:subscription.exists => false).order_by(:ratings_count => 'desc').page(params[:page]).per(50)
end
```

Comment: You're right ! but when I put this code here is the error : undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x007faaee67bfb0>

Comment: we still using schools, remove schoolss variable

Comment: thank you for your time ! actually it work but It's not ordered by ratings count right now

Comment: I forget to precise that I use mongoid !

Comment: @AntoninMrchd just edit answer, changed it to order_by